# The collection has not been initialized on SECOND call of getEnumeration

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I try to receive the subwebs of a users subwebs in SharePoint.
On the first call to receive the subwebs (function getSubWebs()) everything is fine: The subwebs are received and I can iterate through them.

When However I try to get the subwebs of those webs using the same kind of Code
var webSubEnumerator = subwebCollection.getEnumerator(); is throwing the error

```
The collection has not been initialized
```

even though i used Load() before and are inside the "success"-part of the ExecuteQueryAsync (just like on the webs parent request).

What could cause the problem here?

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();
var web = context.get_web();
var lists = web.get_lists();

var parrentwebCollection = null;
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getSubWebs, "sp.js"); 

function getSubWebs(){
  parrentwebCollection = web.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
  context.load(parrentwebCollection)
  context.executeQueryAsync(onGetSubwebsSuccess, onGetSubwebsFail);
}

function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args){
  var webEnumerator = parrentwebCollection.getEnumerator();
  // Everything works FINE on this getEnumerator()

  while (webEnumerator.moveNext()){
    var webParrent = webEnumerator.get_current();
    var parrenttitel = webParrent.get_title();
    var parrenturl = webParrent.get_url();

    //Load Subs From Parrent
    var subwebCollection = null;
    subwebCollection = webParrent.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);

    if (subwebCollection != undefined && subwebCollection != null) { 
      context.load(subwebCollection);
      context.executeQueryAsync(onGetSSubwebsSuccess, onGetSSubwebsFail);

      function onGetSSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
        console.log("getSubWebs query successful")
        var webSubEnumerator = subwebCollection.getEnumerator();
        // THIS getEnumerator(), however throws an exception

        while (webSubEnumerator.moveNext()){
          console.log("After While")
          var subweb = webSubEnumerator.get_current();
          var subtitel = subweb.get_title();
        }              
      }

      function onGetSSubwebsFail(sender, args){
        alert("Request to retrieve subwebs failed. Error: " + args.get_message())
      }
    }
  }              
}

function onGetSubwebsFail(sender, args){
  alert("Request to retrieve subwebs failed. Error: " + args.get_message())
}
```

Please note that I am inside the Success()-function of `executeQueryAsync().` So to my believe **this is not the typical "trying to read asynchronous data before it is there" - problem**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring because you're invoking the callback function multiple times from within a while loop, and the callback function references a variable (`subwebCollection`) from the containing scope -- meaning each invocation of the function accesses the same shared variable (and thus the same shared value) defined in the containing function scope.

(Unlike most programming languages, JavaScript is function-scoped instead of block-scoped.)

You can bypass the problem by using a "closure" within the while loop to ensure each invocation of the callback function has a reference to its own local copy of the variable(s) it needs.

```
function onGetSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
    var webEnumerator = parentwebCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (webEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var webparent = webEnumerator.get_current();
        var parenttitle = webparent.get_title();
        (function(){ /* anonymous function expression wraps the subwebCollection variable in a closure (creates a new scope for the variable) */
            var subwebCollection = null;
            subwebCollection = webparent.getSubwebsForCurrentUser(null);
            if (subwebCollection != undefined && subwebCollection != null) {
                context.load(subwebCollection);
                context.executeQueryAsync(onGetSSubwebsSuccess, onGetSSubwebsFail);
                function onGetSSubwebsSuccess(sender, args) {
                    console.log("getSubWebs query successful")
                    var webSubEnumerator = subwebCollection.getEnumerator();
                    while (webSubEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                        console.log("After While")
                        var subweb = webSubEnumerator.get_current();
                        var subtitel = subweb.get_title();
                    }
                }
                function onGetSSubwebsFail(sender, args) {
                    alert("Request to retrieve subwebs failed. Error: " + args.get_message())
                }
            }
        })(); /* we immediately invoke the function expression */
    }
}
```

This technique is commonly referred to as an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, or IIFE.

```
(function(){
    // closure
})();
```

It's nothing more than a way to force JavaScript to mimic block-level scoping instead of function-level scoping for its variables.